# Что быстрее- хранить значения в памяти Golang или Redis?

Tags: golang, кэширование, redis

Golang довольно быстрый, по сравнению с другими языками.
Вот стало интересно- что будет быстрее- хранить большое количество данным в переменных/картах на go или обращаться к серверу Redis, так как он очень быстрый, да и предоставляет кучу готовых функций, которые б для выборки на go ещё нужно было бы писать.
Кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Таких тестов не делал, но явно работа с редисом по сети будет медленнее, чем с памятью в Go. Тут вопрос в другом: нужен ли вам "локальный" кэш, с которым работает только одно приложение? Если нет и предполагается работа нескольких копий приложения с одним кэшем, то надо смотреть в сторону редиса/мемкеша.

Answer (score 2):

**Go** однозначно быстрее, но для каждого инстанса будет свой кеш, нет возможности шардинга, после ребута или падения инстанса кешированные данные пропадут, также есть проблемы со сборщиком мусора в версиях 1.4x при больших map'ах ([Large maps cause significant GC pauses](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9477)) (в версия 1.5 все ок, в 1.6 еще более ок, там сборщик работает напорядок быстрее, но чтобы вообще избавиться от проверки сборщиком кеша нужно юзать, что-то вроде [BigCache](https://github.com/allegro/bigcache)).

**Redis** медленее, но это не так существенно, если сравнивать с запросами к основной базе данных, имеется возможность шардинга, после падения инстанса кеш восстанивливатся с диска, множество возможностей поверх, также это широкоизвестная KVS, независимая от ЯП, значит легче будет получить помощь.

Если планируется рост и развитие продукта, стоит заморочиться с **Redis**.